# Laravel Nova Many To Many relationship table

Tags: laravel-nova

I have 2 models - Shop and Product with many-to-many relationship. How I can show its like table, where columns is shops and rows is products. In cell must be checkboxes for attaching or detaching product to shop.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `belongsToMany` Eloquent relationship when you say many-to-many? If that is the case then [Nova documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0) are quite clear.

Here is an example directly taken from the documentation ([#belongstomany](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/relationships.html#belongstomany)):

Add the following to your Model Nova resource (`User` in this example):

```php
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\BelongsToMany;

BelongsToMany::make('Roles');
```

Also, if you have additional pivot fields:

```php
BelongsToMany::make('Roles')
    ->fields(function () {
        return [
            Text::make('Notes'),
        ];
    });
```

And the inverse of the relationship (`Roles` resource):

```php
BelongsToMany::make('Users')
    ->fields(function () {
        return [
            Text::make('Notes'),
        ];
    });
```

Note: extra fields are the ones you define within your Eloquent relationship in the `belongsToMany` relationship:

```php
    /**
     * The roles which the user belongs to.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role')
                    ->withPivot(['notes']) // Add extra fields to the 'pivot' object
                    ->withTimestamps(); // Enable timestamps (created_at and updated_at fields)
    }
```

Which then can be accessed from the pivot object:

```php
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
foreach($user->roles as $role){
    echo $role->pivot->notes;
}
```